# Phonegap vs native for ease of developing?

Tags: java, javascript, android, objective-c, cordova

I know it has been asked many times before but I am still confused.
I need to develop an application that works mainly with data, something similar to facebook for example.
I want to target both Android and ios.
I do know some Html/css/javascript though I am not an expert.
I find it very difficult to work with Javascript, difficult to debug etc.
Will it be easier to work with Java/ Objective C?
From my experience .Net is 100 times easier then Javascript. Is it the same with Java/Objective C?

Also I am looking for the long run on how to work in the next projects(which will also be information based), so I am willing to sacrifice time and learn platforms. What will be the learning curve for on against the other, and once you know the platforms, what will be easier?

Another question: do you think there will be a demand for phonegap developers in the future? since I don't think that now it is in demand/use, as the expectations were from this platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Will it be easier? Not so much when you get the hang of it. I have made a web app using PhoneGap and I still liked writing it in the native enviroment (PhoneGap did not produce the results which I have hoped for).
2. If you really have time and you're willing to learn then you should go native. That way you will learn more languages which will benefit you more in the long run. Java is going to be easier if you're used to OOP. But don't be scared of anything. Go for it!
3. In the future? Well JavaScript, HTML5+CSS3 is already popular and might grow even more.
4. Use PhoneGap for small and light apps and not for "Facebook" type apps:)

Thats just my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks. It both answers help. I think I will give a chance as a first time to phonegap since application is light. Also I will get stronger in Html/css/Js which goes well with .Net. If it doesn't work, I will switch to native Android.

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to answer some of your questions:

- If your app is data-intensive (facebook example, a lot of multi
  threads to load a lot of data) you should use native language for
  your app because it will be a lot less slow. I develop both in iOS
  and Android, the learning curve really depends your own experience.
- If you are better at object-oriented languages and have experience
  with listeners Android will be easy as pie. But learning to develop
  in ObjectiveC requires to have some experience with pointers and
  structure/funcion-oriented languages (C,C#,C++). I find Android to be
  easier for beginners tho ;)
- Phonegap at the moment is a very good choice for small, light apps,
  and it's community is growing bigger and bigger (you got Cordova
  also, works just like Phonegap) and if you have experience with web
  development and design it will be a LOT easier to develop your first
  app.

There is a big BUT in using Phonegap/Cordova: the UI is slow at the moment, by that I mean that when you click a button or icon it is somewhat slow to react compared with native...if your app is client-oriented I wouldn't use Phonegap. This "slow" effect worsens with data-heavy apps so take care what you decide.

Hope that I've helped you out, feel free to ask anything ;)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on "if your app is **client-oriented**". Also can you expand more on **data-heavy apps**?. What would you suggest say I want to build a finance app similar to intuit.com incorporating important desktop features.

Comment: **Client-oriented** means you will make your app to sell it to a client, if your app is slower than the average you'll have a harder time selling it. If the app is already payed by the client he will complain that the app is slow but phonegap reduces the development time in cross-platform so he should be happier with paying less for the "almost same" product than in native. **Data-heavy**: an example is facebook, all day loading data constantly (likes, comments, notifications) an app made with phone gap will go really slower than the native one in this case.

Comment: Do you have experience in developing PhoneGap applications for enterprises. What route (native/hybrid) would you suggest for enterprise apps. Where the app is not sold nor is it data centric, but provides an added accessibility to the consumer on the mobile. Take for example Banking apps.

Comment: Would you say that if it is a small light app, the user want suffer too much from performance?

Comment: As I have said before, I think a light app can go just perfect with Phonegap. If the "success" of your app does not depend on its speed (Banking apps are a good example) it is a good idea to use Phonegap. If you are not selling your app and you want to experiment feel free to use Phonegap, it's a lot easier if you've been a web developer before using it and very fast to create a new app. As I have said before: commercial apps or data centric apps, I wouldn't develop them with Phonegap.

Comment: I just want to say I am so happy I chose to go with phonegap. As a .Net developer knowing current web technologies places you much better when you look for a job. On the other hand most jobs that look for naive mobile developer don't appreciate that you know .Net or other server side technology. I felt it on my last job interview. Thanks so much for the answers.

Comment: I tried to upload a photo to server. Testing on iphone 4 I failed many times. So such a simple task, has performance issues. So it not obvious to use phonegap.